# Melhorar codigo css

Tags: css, revisão-de-código

Como posso melhorar a semântica desse código em css.

Ex:
Criei duas div's com atributo display:none; e quando passar o mouse em uma div pai essas div's deveram habilitar-se.

```
.acaoBaixar, .acaoView {  
    display: none;

}
```

Quero melhorar esse código abaixo.

```
/*habilita as div-s  */

.file:hover .acaoBaixar {   
    display: block; 
}
.file:hover .acaoView { 
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Poste a estrutura html também.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não entendo o que quer dizer com "semântica", o seu código é minimo e apresenta algo simples, a unica modificação que eu faria é que se `.acaoBaixar` e `.acaoView` tem o mesmo efeito CSS, então `.file:hover .acaoBaixar` e `.file:hover .acaoView` também devem ter, ou seja não tem porque criar duas regras assim:

```
.file:hover .acaoBaixar {   
    display: block; 
}
.file:hover .acaoView { 
    display: block; 
}
```

Faça apenas uma:

```
.file:hover .acaoBaixar, .file:hover .acaoView { 
    display: block; 
}
```

Pois assim se precisar mudar algo você só mudará em um lugar.

Outra coisa se usar isso em um lugar:

```
.subClasse
```

E isso em outro:

```
.classe .subClasse
```

Você poderá ter problemas com a regra que "tiver preferencia", tente manter a mesma regra, a não ser que `.subClasse` (no exemplo) seja usado fora de `.classe`, então o final ficaria assim:

```
.file .acaoBaixar, .file .acaoView { 
    display: none;
    //...Resto do CSS
}

.file:hover .acaoBaixar, .file:hover .acaoView { 
    display: block; 
}
```

Procure também deixar todas regras na classe principal e não no hover quando usar apenas `display: block;` no hover. Não faz muita diferença, é mais por uma questão de organização.

Comment: Entendi!!
É Isso mesmo que eu estava tentando implementar, deixar o código menos repetitivo. muito obrigado!